# Deserialize XML element returning null value

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have some data in an XML file. I am trying to deserialize the XML to some classes I have created.

I have been able to deserialize all the attributes of the `PointCode` and `CodeAttributes` elements. However, I can't seem to get the `TextListValue` attribute of the `textList` element.

The `textList` element returns a null value.
I am using c# and using System.Xml.Serialization

```cs
[XmlRoot("PointCode")]
public class PointCode
{
    [XmlAttribute("codeLinework")]
    public string codeLinework { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CodeAttributes")]
    public List<CodeAttributes> codeAttributes { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("CodeAttributes")]
public class CodeAttributes
{
    [XmlAttribute("attributeName")]
    public string attributeName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("attributeType")]
    public string attributeType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("valueType")]
    public string valueType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("valueRegion")]
    public string valueRegion { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("text")]
    public Text text { get; set; }

}

[XmlRoot("text")]
public class Text
{
    [XmlElement("textChoiceList")]
    public TextChoiceList textChoiceList { get; }
}

[XmlRoot("textChoiceList")]
public class TextChoiceList
{
    [XmlElement("textList")]
    public List<TextList> textList { get; set; }

}

[XmlRoot("textList")]
public class TextList
{
    [XmlAttribute("textListValue")]
    public string textListValue { get; set; }
}
```

Extract of the XML file I am deserializing.

```
<Code codeName="KERB" codeDesc="Kerbs" codeType="Point">
  <PointCode codeLinework="open line">
    <CodeAttributes attributeName="String" attributeType="Normal" valueType="Integer" valueRegion="None">
      <integer />
    </CodeAttributes>
    <CodeAttributes attributeName="Type" attributeType="Normal" valueType="Text" valueRegion="ChoiceList">
      <text>
        <textChoiceList>
          <textList textListValue="Square Kerb" />
          <textList textListValue="Roll Kerb" />
        </textChoiceList>
      </text>
    </CodeAttributes>
```

Comment: You are missing the "set" : public TextChoiceList textChoiceList { get; }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing setter for `textChoiceList` property in the `Text` class that leads to the `text` was `null` as the only property in the class is unable to set value.

So adding the missing setter to the property will solve the issue.

```cs
[XmlRoot("text")]
public class Text
{
    [XmlElement("textChoiceList")]
    public TextChoiceList textChoiceList { get; set; }
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xeJUKQ)